# Why is Application.Run a member of the Excel library whereas CallByName works in general for all VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, com, idispatch, ole-automation

`Excel.Application.Run` and `VBA.Interaction.CallByName` both seem to do similar things; namely calling a method using a string name. As I understand it, this functionality is enabled because VBA is an *automation* language and uses `IDispatch` for a lot of its objects and internal working.

What has this got to do with `Excel` then (or indeed `PowerPoint.Application.Run`)? Why is calling members of standard modules vs class modules so different?

Comment: Very similar, but don't quite do the same thing.  Application.Run() does more, it can also find and execute macros, lookup a formula from a Range object and execute XLL functions.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay didn't know, but I guess what I'm really interested in is the calling from a standard module, why is this not built into VBA like calling from a class module is?

Comment: The other stuff on formulae and ranges could be implemented separately by the host application, but calling methods of standard modules feels to me to be host-agnostic, so I'm wondering; is it/why is it not?

Comment: VBA is heavily COM-centric at its core.  Which does not have anything resembling a module (beyond the quirky appobject), its interface-based programming paradigm requires objects.